# LoadRunner Vugen script fails in controller

Tags: controller, loadrunner, vugen

When I run a script in LoadRunner Controller, I am getting the following error:

> Action.c(76): Error: Tree - Failed to select node "" Snapshot Info [MSH 0 0 1].

The thing is that the script works perfectly in the Vugen. Anyone has ever found something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this: I used this method to explore the tree

sapgui_tree_double_click_node

I changed this method for:

sapgui_tree_scroll_to_node

and now the Controller works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for expected page results and branch your code accordingly when you do not receive an expected page.  Based upon your error you are likely trying to select a link which does not exist on the page returned.

Comment: The problem is that the controller gets the first element of a menu and open its submenu, but it's not able to select nor double click any element of the submenu. Just doesn't find it.